# How to set database value to CKEditor placeholder?

Tags: database, codeigniter, ckeditor, placeholder

I'm using CKEditor 4 to replace the  when creating an e-mail message. The message is mostly business letter template. I want to replace the some part such as  in the letter template values from the database.

While searching CKEditor site, I found out this [placeholder plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder). I know how to add the plugin to my CKEditor. BUt I wanna know how can I set this placeholder a value from my php variable. This variable holds database field column content for example $first_name.

I did search SO for any similar question but they usually skip the part I'm looking for.

Any suggestion is really appreciated

Thank you SO.

Comment: Why not using the placeholder text as a replaceable {tag}? Save the email template with a text like "Dear {f_name}" and then when you are sending this email you can `str_replace('{f_name}', $user['name'], $output_email['body']);` I can write a more explaining answer but I don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's it!..that's what I'm looking for. Yes, please can you provide example. This is very helpful. Thank you for sharing your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using the CKEditor with the placeholder plugin you may have a text/html email template saved in your database with something like

```
Dear {f_name},
You owe us {money} Euros.
```

The tags `{f_name}` and `{money}` are examples and can be the placeholders you want.
When you are populating the text for each email sent you can make a function like the following:

```
$email['body'] = $this->emails_model->fetch_your_email_body();
foreach ($users as $user){

    $email['body'] = str_replace('{f_name}', $user['first_name'], $email['body'] );
    $email['body'] = str_replace('{money}', $user['amount_to_pay'], $email['body']);

    $this->email->message($email['body']);
    $this->email->send()// send your email to each user (with or w/o the CI email class)
}
```

This will send a personalised email for every user you have in your $users array.